# MYSQL Delete all rows with the minimum DATE value

Tags: mysql, sql

In MYSQL, I have a dataset which contains **stock data** of **many many** dates, and I want to **delete all** the rows that have the **lowest date** value (my date value is an integer, so in other words, I want to delete trades from the first date). I have found this code on stack overflow, but it only deletes one row, while I want to **delete** ALL rows with this minimum date.

This is the code I have found.

```
DELETE FROM TABLE 
ORDER BY DATE
LIMIT 1
```

Thank you!

Comment: This is my first question, so please feel free to let me know what the correct formatting is for asking questions :) Thanks!

Comment: Please check this below query and let me know if any question regard this.

Comment: Please check the below answer where use your given column name except DBO.

Answer (score 0):

Use a query to find out minimum date then delete all records for this date.

```
-- MySQL
DELETE t
FROM TEST_TRADES t
INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(ï»¿COB_DATE) a
              FROM TEST_TRADES) tt
        ON t.ï»¿COB_DATE = tt.a
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4262ea268d2d9ba9b617142edf536cdc

Comment: Hi Rahul, I get an error when running this code - I think MySQL does not allow the delete command to work with the select command. (Error Code: 1093)

Comment: Please check now. Mysql doesn't support

Comment: Please check my url where you'll get code with sample data.

Comment: Hi Rahul, I did check your code in the url, but it is still returning error for me... Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Few unknown character with column name cob_date. This can generate error. It's totally my assumption. Which version of mysql u use. Please provide table structure with sample data. My given query is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to this question:
This is what I've done:
SELECT @MIN_DATE := MIN(DATE) FROM TABLE T;
DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE T.DATE = @MIN_DATE